# VoIP Technology

Tags: audio

Good evening,

I have a project to create a chat on a website (ReactJS or Angular)
I would like users to be able to access an audio conference call.

I discovered WebRTC but the communication is peer to peer.
Do you know of any good technology that would allow you to communicate by voice through our server?
Like the Discord application for example.

I have no experience in this field.

Thank you !

Comment: Will the end-user just use a microphone connected to their computer to send voice into the voice chat through the website ? That's how Skype works. Otherwise a softphone installed on their computer could access a VoIP conference-call-room and that's if they had a VoIP service and if they called-in additional to the website connection.

Comment: Oh, a button click on the website could call the phone number of the end-user and connect them as a participant of a conference-call.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want to do like Skype.
What technology does it use for the web version?

Comment: Skype is proprietary but they might offer a service where a website link can be re-branded to a voice chat. Otherwise, I looked at customer systems on the Twilio website and all I found was a button click on a website that calls a customer. VoIP conference calls are easy to find but is a service of VoIP service providers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webcall.me](https://webcall.me) to add voice chat in your project for less than a minute

Here are the steps:

1. Download the app from google play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=webcall.me and login with your google account
2. You will receive automatic email with two links
3. Add one of the links into your project

Basically it is phone call from link (webrtc) and you can create unlimited links and talk unlimited minutes. 
The only disadvantage that I can see is that does not support conference calls

It is completely Free app without ads

You can login on multiple devices with the same account

Comment: I tried it seems fine.